# Return a QuerySet of lists grouped by date

Tags: python, django

I have a Transaction model in my database which stores all of my banking transactions and displays them on a page. They are all listed but the list is very long. To shorten it, I want to group them by month/year so I can create a collapsible list on the page with all months collapsed except for the current month. A long search only returns the aggregate and annotate functions (which I don't fully understand). The closest I've gotten is this:

```
>>> data = Transaction.objects.annotate(month=TruncMonth('date')).values('month').annotate(c=Count('id')).values('month', 'c')
>>> data
<QuerySet [{'month': datetime.date(2016, 12, 1), 'c': 74}, {'month': datetime.date(2017, 1, 1), 'c': 109}, {'month': datetime.date(2017, 2, 1), 'c': 70}, {'month': datetime.date(2017, 3, 1), 'c': 92}, {'month': datetime.date(2017, 4, 1), 'c': 79}, {'month': datetime.date(2017, 5, 1), 'c': 79}, {'month': datetime.date(2017, 6, 1), 'c': 83}, {'month': datetime.date(2017, 7, 1), 'c': 99}, {'month': datetime.date(2017, 8, 1), 'c': 98}, {'month': datetime.date(2017, 9, 1), 'c': 112}, {'month': datetime.date(2017, 10, 1), 'c': 87}, {'month': datetime.date(2017, 11, 1), 'c': 82}, {'month': datetime.date(2017, 12, 1), 'c': 86}, {'month': datetime.date(2018, 1, 1), 'c': 113}, {'month': datetime.date(2018, 2, 1), 'c': 98}, {'month': datetime.date(2018, 3, 1), 'c': 121}, {'month': datetime.date(2018, 4, 1), 'c': 111}, {'month': datetime.date(2018, 5, 1), 'c': 107}, {'month': datetime.date(2018, 6, 1), 'c': 91}, {'month': datetime.date(2018, 7, 1), 'c': 97}, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

As you can see, this just counts the transactions which occurred on the same month/year. I want to actually have all the transactions listed out.

Here is my Transaction model:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
   date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.description
```

Comment: Are the hidden (collapsed) parts also rendered and just hidden, or will you make a new database query when the user chooses to open a collapsed month?

Comment: They are rendered and hidden. I already have that part figured out, just trying to get it to the page grouped like that. Don't know if the answer is to just group it in the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to do the grouping in the view.

You could iterate over your queryset in your view and assign the records to sublists per year/month/whatever; then pass those sublists to your template for rendering.

```
import collections

data = collections.defaultdict(list)
for t in Transaction.objects.all():
    group = (t.date.year, t.date.month)
    data[group].append(t)
```

In this code snippet, the variable `data` is a `dict` that has year-month as its keys and lists of `Transaction` (corresponding to that year and month) as the values.

That way you avoid a complex query if you are going to render all the records anyways.

Comment: That mostly worked. I just had to convert back to a regular dict to be able to access the data when I passed it to the template